# How to rename multiple files in single command or script in Unix?

Tags: linux, shell-script, rename

I have the below list of files

```
aro_tty-mIF-45875564pmo_opt
aro_tty-mIF-45875664pmo_opt
aro_tty-mIF-45875964pmo_opt
aro_tty-mIF-45875514pmo_opt
aro_tty-mIF-45875524pmo_opt
```

that I need to rename to

```
aro_tty-mImpFRA-45875564pmo_opt
aro_tty-mImpFRA-45875664pmo_opt
aro_tty-mImpFRA-45875964pmo_opt
aro_tty-mImpFRA-45875514pmo_opt
aro_tty-mImpFRA-45875524pmo_opt
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Most standard shells provide a way to do simple text substitution within shell variables. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html explains as follows:

```
${var/Pattern/Replacement}

First match of Pattern, within var replaced with Replacement.
```

So use this script to loop through all the appropriate files and rename each of them:

```
for file in aro_tty-mIF-*_opt
do
    mv -i "${file}" "${file/-mIF-/-mImpFRA-}"
done
```

I have added a -i option so you have the chance to confirm each renaming operation. As always, you should make a backup of all your files before doing any large amount of renaming or deleting.

Comment: Strangely, the -i option doesn't prompt for y/n before renaming files on the Redhat system I am on.  Anyone know why?

Comment: Does the `-i` option to `mv` have no effect even when you're typing it to the shell directly (not using `find`)?

Comment: Good call.  Looks like I do not have that feature on the shared Red Hat server I am using.

Comment: That's unusual. Does `type mv` show something other than `mv is /usr/bin/mv` ? Someone could have made it an alias or a function.

Comment: no, actually. It says "mv is hashed (/bin/mv)" not sure what that means.

Comment: "Hashed" is just a feature of your shell.  `/bin/mv` is a plausible location for mv.  As for mv not honoring the `-i` option, that's not standard. Maybe you have an older system or someone installed a custom version of mv.

Comment: What does this `-mIF-/-mImpFRA-` syntax mean, where can I find doc for it?

Comment: @YngvarKristiansen Those strings are parts of the filenames used by the original poster. They're not command options or anything like that.

Answer (score 21):

If you don't have Perl's `rename`:

```
perl -e '
FILE:for $file (@ARGV){
        ($new_name = $file) =~ s/-mIF-/-mImpFRA-/
        next FILE if -e $new_name;
        rename $file => $new_name
}' *_opt
```

If you *do* have Perl's `rename`:

```
rename 's/-mIF-/-mImpFRA-/' *_opt
```

Comment: @Udhayakumar Why does the solution need to use `mv`?

Answer (score 17):

Before trying complex commands like the following, **backup your files**. You never know what a typo (mine or yours) can cause.

With `mv` (as you asked in comment --- `rename` as suggested in the other answer is probably safer, especially if you can have spaces or strange chars in your filenames) something of the style

```
for f in *_opt; do
    a="$(echo $f | sed s/-mIF-/-mImpFRA-/)"
    mv "$f" "$a"
done
```