# Renaming files using mv in bash on MacOS (moving substring in filename)

Tags: bash, rename, mv, macos

I'm trying to bulk rename files in `bash` on MacOS.

```
PREFIX - Full Title 1 012346.txt
```

I'm trying to rename them to be:

```
012346 - PREFIX - Full Title 1.txt
```

How can I do this in the shell using `mv` only?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following script:

```
for f in *.txt ; do
    if [[ "$f" =~  ^(PREFIX)\ -\ (.*)\ ([0-9]{6})\.txt$ ]]; then
        mv -v "${f}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}\ -\ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} - ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.txt"
    fi
done
```

It was based on the following answers:

- [Move last part of filename to front](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444825/move-last-part-of-filename-to-front)
- [How to rename multiple files in single command or script in Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102647/how-to-rename-multiple-files-in-single-command-or-script-in-unix)
- [How can I rename a lot of files using a regex?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24107/how-can-i-rename-a-lot-of-files-using-a-regex)